# PDF not being deployed in assets using vite

Tags: javascript, build, vite

I have a static site that has a pdf asset which is not getting deployed. I tried looking in the vite docs and I'm assuming there's a config somewhere to specify to include pdfs, but I can't find it.

I saw I can create a public folder at the root directory and might be able to just specify it there, but was hoping  there was a way I can get it deployed with my other assets in my src/assets folder

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe this might solve my issue.
https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#assetsinclude

Comment: Have you resolved this? how?  `assetsInclude: ['**/*.pdf'],` didn't work for me